# Excluding '#' comments from a sed selection

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to get a config value from a yml file but there is one line that has that same value, but commented out. That is:

```
...
    #database_name: prod
    database_name: demo
    database_user: root
    database_password: password
...
```

I'm getting all values with this sed/awk command:

```
DATABASE_NAME=$(sed -n '/database_name/p' "$CONFIG_PATH" | awk -F' ' '{print $2}');
```

Now, if I do that, I get the right values for the user and password, but get double name.

Question is:

**How do I exclude '#' comments from my sed selection?**

Comment: If you're parsing a YAML file, then perhaps consider using a YAML parser :-/

Comment: Sure, do you know a command line yaml parser? I know there are a bunch of tools out there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is always a character before the `d` use `/[^#]database_name/p`.

If not you can use `/\(^\|[^#]\)database_name/p`.

Answer (score 2):

You might as well use `awk` for the whole operation:

```
DATABASE_NAME=$(awk -F' ' '$1!~/^#/ && /database_name/{print $2}' "$CONFIG_PATH")
```

This will exclude all lines that start with `#` (comments).

Comment: Or just `$1=="database_name:"{print $2}` if the colon is always there flush up against `database_name`.

Comment: It's YAML so it should always be there.

Comment: @mimoralea If the name of the database is all you want and is always the same format, you could use awk, sed, grep etc. But *be careful*: YAML format may change and `database_name` may not be on a separate line (awk, sed etc solutions break). I normally use [PyYaml](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML) to parse YAML file to parse yaml file (perl has support too).

Answer (score 1):

I think the braces are a GNU sed feature (not sure though)

```
sed -n '/database_name/ {/^[[:blank:]]*#/!p}'
```

For lines matching "database_name", if the line does NOT begin with blanks and a hash then print it.

Answer (score 1):

if the file has blank spaces at starting of lines:

```
 sed 's/ //g' file.txt | awk '/^(database)/{print}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using @etan-reisner solution.

Here is another solution to my particular problem I found along the way:

```
DATABASE_NAME=$(cat "$CONFIG_PATH" | grep -v '^[[:space:]]*#' | sed -n '/database_host/p' | awk -F' ' '{print $2}');
```

This will filter every line that contains some spaces followed by a hash.